# Repeatable Background line in Table for HTML Email

Tags: html

I've been looking all over for a tutorial on how to make repeatable lines in an HTML email. Here is a portion of the code that im using in the table:

```
 <td colspan="2"><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" height="5" background="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thryll/email-images/line-piece.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-x;"></table></td>
```

I've tried several other tutorials without any success. There has to be a way to do this considering it was done in the attached picture from another email. It's even working in

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer this question with certainty as a lot of this kind of thing depends on the e-mail client you're using. Outlook 2007 & 10 are notoriously difficult to keep happy.

There's lots of info at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/ in relation to background images on tables specifically.

[image]

Comment: You cannot dependably use background images in email messages.

Answer (score 0):

This question looks unfinished at the moment.
So far, I can only point out that you have a `</table>` tag before the `</td>` tag.
Unless you have a table within a table, this is incorrect nesting, and while it *may* display correctly in some browsers, it's not valid XHTML, and generally bad practice.

Comment: First time using Stackoverflow for questions so thank you so much for the quick response. Im compare code from a fab.com email I receive:

Comment: Sorry that was incomplete: First time using Stackoverflow for questions so thank you so much for the quick response. Im compare code from a fab.com email I receive: They seem to have nailed it in out look with the following: <tr><td style="padding:15px 31px 0px"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="617" height="6" backgorund="image" style="background-repeat-x; background-color:#fffff></table